# Is the comparator $U(y,x)$ in Gauge Theory the same as a holonomy?

Tags: notation, fiber-bundles, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, holonomy

For Gauge theories you have a comparator that transforms as
$$U(y,x) = e^{i\alpha(y)}U(y,x) e^{-i\alpha(x)}$$
Is this the same thing as the holonomy?